# Issue with "video_path" helper Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, video, heroku

Up until recently I've been using "video_path" to populate source urls for videos playing within my site.

IE:

```
<video class="header-video" muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="<%= video_path("test.mp4") %>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It worked as intended producing "/videos/test.mp4"

Yesterday however, I pushed a new build to heroku prematurely and then rolled it back. After fixing some things, I pushed up a corrected build, but now "video_path" is producing "/videos.test.mp4" instead. I cant for the life of me figure out why. It's doing so in both my local and production environments for this site. Other rails sites I have however, are still producing the proper urls as intended.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command:
`~/app_dir$ bundle exec rake routes | grep video`

Comment: @AhmedSamirShahin thanks for the response. Running that I get "/video(.:format)"

Comment: mm .. it definitely something related to wrong routing rules, can you provide me with any `video` routes from `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @AhmedSamirShahin Turns out I'm just an idiot. Your questions put me down the right path. I thought I had a route listed as "/videos" however I had typed "/video" which changed the functionality of the "video_path" helper in the process. Im all good now. Thanks again for your help.